# Extend angular-cli build process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I'd like to know how I can extend angular-cli build process.

I want to add additional JSON file to `/dist` folder after cli finishes its work.
I can't see a way to add any callback in `angular-cli-build.js`.

I tried:

```
var Angular2App = require( 'angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app' );
var ngCliVersion = require( './ng-cli-version' );

module.exports = function ( defaults ) {
  /* CREATE JSON FILE CONTAINS INFO ABOUT BUILD VERSION AND GIT COMMIT */
  ngCliVersion.createVersionFile();

  return new Angular2App( defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/*.js',
      'core-js/client/shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/*.js',
      'rxjs/**/*.js',
      '@angular/**/*.js'
    ]
  } );
};
```

The problem is that cli wipes `dist` folder before it starts so file I created is removed.

How then extend build process properly without hacking cli?

Comment: Just add your file to `public/` folder, it will be copied to `dist/` as is...

Comment: @Sasxa that is the correct approach to use here, can you please put that in the form of an answer so it can be accepted and found/used by others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy a file in build process, you just need to add it to the `public/` folder and it will be copied to `dist/` folder.

I couldn't find any documentation to quote here, other then this [function in source files](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/8307c14c507322fa5dc4f1a429709c76692762fc/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js#L89-L91), but here's something from [Ember CLI](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-include-folder-of-assets-into-ember-app-with-ember-cli/7763) docs.